# Elasticsearch aggregation by correlation field ( join / lookup like )

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I am new to elasticsearch , attempting to understand if there is easy option to get a list from mongo logs injested in elastic search correlated by connection ID  , the log events look as follow:

```
 {"t":{"$date":"2024-01-29T07:39:23.364+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn1782915","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"192.168.0.25:17954","client":"conn1782915","doc":{"driver":{"name":"mongo-java-driver|sync","version":"4.6.1"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"Linux","architecture":"amd64","version":"5.15.128-202.epo.fc38.x86_64"},"platform":"Java","mongos":{"host":"myhost:27017","client":"192.168.0.25:17954","version":"6.0.12"}}}}
 {"t":{"$date":"2024-01-29T07:39:23.379+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20250,   "ctx":"conn1782915","msg":"Authentication succeeded","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","speculative":true,"principalName":"myuser","authenticationDatabase":"admin","remote":"192.168.0.25:17954","extraInfo":{}}}
```

In the above example we see two events :

1. Network event( conn1782915 ) that contain the driver version: {"name":"mongo-java-driver|sync","version":"4.6.1"}
2. Access event ( conn1782915 ) that contain the principalName: myuser

So here is the question:

Is there an option in Elasticsearch to aggregate with correlation based on connectionID ( conn1782915 )?

So I get the following output in CSV or KIBANA dashboard:

```
driver                         user          count()
mongo-java-driver|sync-4.6.1 , myuser   ,       34
mongo-java-driver|sync-4.6.1 , otherUser ,     125
```

P.S. The goal is to get a list on demand of users that need their drivers updated ( e.g get driver version from event 1 and username from event 2 )  , the count of correlated events is even not so important ...
The main problem is that conn1782915 is unique for few seconds and maybe duplicated in time with other connections so with simple agregation maybe not possible , it best to be done at injestion time ...